# Access protected API from off-chain worker

Tags: offchain-worker, security

Is it possible to access a protected API from an off-chain worker, e.g. using an API Key? Hard coding the API Key would be possible, but that's obviously a security risk. Is there a safe mechanism to share this kind of sensitive information with the off-chain worker? The only related information I've found is [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/6512) but it looks like no solution was found.